# Is the Riemann-Stieltjes-Integral the same as the integral with respect to a measure with density?

Tags: measure-theory

In our functional analysis class we quickly introduced the Riemann-Stieltjes-Integral as follows:

If $g$ is a function of bounded variation on $[a,b]$ and $f$ is a step function with values $c_i$ in the intervals $(t_{i-1},t_i)$, where $\{t_0,...,t_N\}$ is a partition of $[a,b]$, then its Riemann-Stieltjes-Integral is defined as
\begin{equation}\int_a^bf(t)dg(t):=\sum_{i=1}^Nc_i(g(t_i)-g(t_{i-1})).
\end{equation}
As $g$ is of bounded variation, this can easily seen to be continuous on the space $SF[a,b]$ of step functions on the interval [a,b], so it has a unique extension to $cl(SF[a,b])^{|| • ||_{\infty}}\supset C([a,b])$. This extension is also called Riemann-Stieltjes-Integral.

On the other hand, I‘m familiar with the concept of a measure with density, i.e. if $\mu$ is some measure, then
\begin{equation}\lambda(A):=\int \chi_A g d\mu
\end{equation} is also a measure on the same sigma-algebra (assuming $g$ is non-negative and measurable).

I was wondering how these are related. In which cases are these the same? I know from basic measure theory that
\begin{equation}\int f d\lambda=\int f g d\mu.
\end{equation}So can we then say
\begin{equation}\int_a^b f(t)dg(t)=\int_a^b f(t)g(t)dt?
\end{equation}

If this is correct, I‘d be glad for outlines or ideas of proof (or on which other results they relay on).

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Your formula is wrong. What is true is if $g$ is smooth (and $g'$ is integrable) then $\int_a^{b}f(t)dg(t)=\int_a^{b} f(t)g'(t)dt$.